# $.ajax and webmethod/pagemethods

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call a pagemethod that doesn't have any parameters, and I can't seem to get it working.

If I have a single parameter in the pagemethod it works fine.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/getLastCallData",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    alert(msg.d);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Couldnt get call data');
  }
});
```

Any ideas.

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen?

Comment: The method on the page never gets hit. The text status from the error callback is parsererror.

Comment: I would suggest using a generic handler (.ASHX) rather than trying to get a web-page (.ASPX) to return JSON data.

Comment: @stusmith - why bother? Callbacks to ASPX pages work fine and keep your code with the HTML that it needs to work with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not passing any data, you should still add the data parameter and pass an empty JSON object.

By sending an empty JSON object, jQuery will correctly send the contentType you defined in the $.ajax call.  This is a weird quirk that jQuery has that hasn't really been explained.

Add the following parameter:

```
data: "{}"
```

So your call should look like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/getLastCallData",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    alert(msg.d);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Couldnt get call data');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching `POST` for `GET`? Don't know if that makes any difference, but since you're not sending any data, you're not really posting anything, you're just getting data...might be something weird going on there.