# Call ASP.NET web service method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, webmethod

I have the web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SendMail(string _name, string _email, string _message)
{
    //Create Mail Message Object with content that you want to send with mail.
    MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("gglebati@example.com", "gglebati@example.com", "This is the mail subject", "Just wanted to say Hello");

    MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

    //Proper Authentication Details need to be passed when sending email from gmail
    NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential("myxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx");

    //Smtp Mail server of Gmail is "smpt.gmail.com" and it uses port no. 587
    //For different server like yahoo this details changes and you can
    //get it from respective server.
   SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

    //Enable SSL
    mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;

    mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);
}
```

and i have a html page. How can i call this function from my html page? (This function must send the message to email)

Comment: possible duplicate of [$.ajax and webmethod/pagemethods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458969/ajax-and-webmethod-pagemethods)

Comment: Are you willing to add the jQuery library?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - I don't see this as a duplicate of THAT page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery library. It makes ajax calls piece a cake. Then follow these items:

1. Add an HTML button to your page, so that people can start the ajax process by clicking it
2. Use jQuery to hook into the click event of that button (or span, or a div, or anything else)
3. Make sure you have `ScriptService` attribute on your web service (this attribute means that you can call your service from JavaScript)
4. Send items to your web service method

   ```
    $('#buttonId').click(function(){
        // Validating input
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '/your-web-service-path.asmx/your-method-name',
           data: {} 
           dataType: 'json',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           success: function(r){},
           error: function(e){}
        });
   });
   ```

Just note that you have to make a JSON object out of your parameters and the name of the JSON properties should match the name of the web service parameters. Also note that the return value of the web service would be available to you as `r.d` object passed to success callback of ajax call.

Comment: how can i post the parameters:(string _name, string _email, string _message) >?

Comment: create this object: `{string_name: 'value1', string_email: 'value2', string_message: 'value3'}`.

Comment: @_glebati: see where data:{}? You can put:data: {'_message':'hello world','_name':'john smith','_email':'john@example.com' }. The important thing is that your parameter names in the web service match the names on the data parameter on the javascript side and that the data parameter is valid JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an aspx page, you can add a ScriptManager with EnablePageMethods="true"attribute, and then call PageMethods.sendMail(name, email, message, onSuccess, onFail);

Comment: it is simle html page with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to take a look at jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) capabilities.

Comment: +1 because this is a valid answer, but you should provide a little more detail.

Comment: kind'a like saying "you might want to read .Net Web Services documentation @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950421.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something very important: Add the ScriptService attribute the class so that it can be called from a Javascript as in this example:

```
[ScriptService]
public class SimpleWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
    // ...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the three parameters from the cs code page, by calling like this way,

```
service.SendMail(name, email, message);
```