# Calling C# webservice method from javascript

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call ASP.NET web service method from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270532/call-asp-net-web-service-method-from-javascript)

Calling C# web service method from java script
i.e webserivces method to be called through java script or XML DOM

Answer (score 1):

Inside `document.ready`:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service.svc/WebServiceMethodName",
        data: JSON2.stringify({ UrParameter: UrparameterValue}),//Parameter to pass
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
         //Do Some Stuff here

        }

    })
```

Dont forget to include `js` and `json2.js`.Its a sample code.U can modify it as your requirement.