# How can I Call Code Behind Method from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I'm have few days reading and searching an answer for this question but I don't found.

I'm using this code

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Default.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
            })
            return false;
        });
        });
```

for try to call C# Method

```
[WebMethod]
 public void ServerSideMethod() {//Do something}
```

But I could not found any solution that work....

Comment: I think your using plain asp.net?! Where does the method live?

Comment: Sorry... I'm using WebForms. The Method is in the code behind...

Comment: Show us the method.  I believe it should be `static` and marked with the `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Comment: The problem with [WebMethod] and static Method is I cannot access to non-static Method and can manage database connections... I need use none-static method...

Comment: you cannot use non-static methods for webmethods and thus non-static methods within the body of the method itself.

Comment: There are another way to call code behind non-static method?

Comment: @Omixam, If you want to calla non static method, you can create the web method in a asmx web service, istead of keeping it in codebehind.

Comment: I have WebForm app, there are any way for add an web service inside the current app?

Answer (score 3):

For it to work, ensure that the method location set in `url` is correct and that the method is `public` and `static` and that is has a `[WebMethod]` attribute added such as:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void doAll()
{
    //do something
}
```

if the `url` is "/Default.aspx/ServerSideMethod" then your method should look like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ServerSideMethod()
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: How can I pass data to the method? For example, if I want the method to receive an integer, how can I do that?

Comment: Hi! something like this `public static void ServerSideMethod(int x)` then in the ajax `post` pass the value in the `data` part.

Comment: Do I have to use POST? Can I pass data if I'm using 'location.href'?

Comment: are you using jquery? then you will need to use post but as I don't know how you're going about things maybe try searching for what you need or open a question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in js:

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {
        // this calls default.aspx 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Default.aspx',
            data: "{ServerSideMethod : '1'}", // send a parameter, to tell it what we want
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            function(data){
                // data is json sent from server, if not, try $.parseJSON(data)
                // do something here after the server side code has finished
                if(data.ok){
                    //success from server side
                }
            }  
        });
        return false;
    });
    });
```

And in Default.aspx.cs:

```
    // fires anytime default.aspx is loaded
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // check if is ajax call and not normal page load in the browser
        if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
             Response.Clear();  //empty everithing so we don't send mixed content
             // no cache on ajax, IE caches ajas if this is missing
             Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Today.AddMilliseconds(1.0));
             Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
             // here we are checking what we want to do, what client side asked
             if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["ServerSideMethod"])) // this will be "1"
             {
                  doAll(); // do your work
             }
             Response.End();
        }
    }

    private void doAll() 
    {
            // do work, then send some json, as this is what you expect         
            // JavaScriptSerializer is located in System.Web.Script.Serialization
            Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { ok = 1, error = 0 }));
    }
```

Comment: With your suggestion I can access to code behind from javascript and execute ServerSideMethod(), although all code of this function is executed, anything change occurred in client-side...

Comment: @omixam I don't understand what are you saying, I think that you want to stop the rest of the page load event? Editing now to have that too.

Comment: I have been testing for few hours this suggestion and I found that I need use an UpdatePanel for do work this... But inside the UpdaatePanel the RowCommand let it work....

Comment: Other observation the application never enter to  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["ServerSideMethod"]))   I commented this line...

Comment: @omixam There is no need to use UpdatePanel for this. This is complete as it is. UpdatePanel just makes postbacks masked as ajax requests, but the ajax is already there.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I would suggest you to write some debug statements. write some output in the first lines of doAll(). it will in fact lets you know if you are really sending the request from the browser to your server. I mean if there is any link to your server at the `url: "/Default.aspx/ServerSideMethod",`. I am thinking you are doing ajax call but you are not starting the server at all OR there is no listener that links this URL to your method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a non static method from ajax, I suggest you to create a **web service** and call it from javascript. You can have non static methods inside a web service.

There are quite a lot of examples in Stackoverflow on how to call a web service from javascript.
[Call ASP.NET web service method from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270532/call-asp-net-web-service-method-from-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

asp.net Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <%--
     you can remove dropdown if asp.net Render __doPostBack already for You.
    --%>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="__doPostBack('CallFromJavaScript','Message from JavaScript')" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and Code Behinde.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string funcationName = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
                string org = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
                if (funcationName == "CallFromJavaScript")
                {
                    CallFromJavaScript(org);
                }
            }
        }


        protected void CallFromJavaScript(string Data)
        {
            Response.Write(DateTime.Now);
        }


    }
}
```

May be This Trick help full For You

Comment: Thats not work... Can I access and execute the function but anithing change occurred in the client-site...